# AlertView error Expected':'

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)showMessageError {
alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Impossible"
                                                  message:@"Here are the problems:\n%@,\n%@,\n%@",self.Error1,self.Error2,self.Error3
                                                 delegate:self
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alertMessage show];
}
```

I simply want to show this AlertView with only cancelButtonTitle but i receive an error near delegate:self
Expected':'

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alertMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Impossible"
                                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Here are the problems:\n%@,\n%@,\n%@",self.Error1,self.Error2,self.Error3]
                                             delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

try this

Comment: Thanks, that works! (hoping to have soon points to give you credits) :)

Comment: @PratyushaTerli It's yours. The second `nil` didn't help him.

Comment: @PratyushaTerli i'm new at stackoverflow and i click on up arrow to give credits to good answers, but i receive a message i've to gain 15 reputation points, now i click to this answer is good, there're 2 different feedback ? I'm a bit confused ... :)